# O que de fato faz o "new" do PHP ao instanciar uma classe?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Tenho uma classe chamada **Setup** com alguns métodos estáticos. Mas estou tendo dificuldade de entender algo que acontece.

Eu utilizo os métodos da classe da seguinte forma: `Setup::$getMetodoX` até ai tudo bem. Porém para facilitar seu uso e não ter que incluir a classe em varias páginas, faço um include dessa classe no meu `HEAD`.

Mas ao olhar o `head` notei a seguinte linha de código: `$setup = new Setup();`. Então resolvi remover essa linha, já que sei que uma classe de métodos estáticos não deve receber uma instanciação através do `new` do PHP.

Porém para minha surpresa. Ao remover essa linha meu sistema perde seu estilo (css). Entretanto, essa variável `$setup` que instancia a minha classe não é usada em lugar nenhum do meu projeto.

Por isso, gostaria de entender se esse `new` do PHP tem mais alguma função além de instanciar uma classe?

Comment: Já viu que erros/warnings dá o PHP. É que o não aparecimento do estilo pode indicar um erro no PHP. Já viu na consola do browser se está a ser carregado o css?

Comment: Não ocorre nenhum erro, nem warning no PHP. mas quando eu comento a linha citada todos os arquivos js e css geram erro no carregamento. A minha página carrega normal mas sem estilo. Porém sem mensagens de erro do PHP, fica complicado entender o que pode estar acontecendo.

Comment: É porque deverá ter alguma coisa que indique o caminho dos ficheiros nessa classe. Já verificou o que tem no construtor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No PHP as classes não tem definição do tipo ou visibilidade.

Exemplo, algo do tipo não existe:

```
static class Foo{

}
```

Isso é apenas nos métodos e propriedades.

```
class Foo
{
    puclic static $bar;

    public static QualquerCoisa()
    {


    }

}
```

Porém, mesmo que todos os métodos e propriedades sejam estáticos, nada impede de invocar como um instância

```
$c = new Foo();
```

Nesse caso, conforme resposta do @Maniero, é invocado o método construtor automaticamente, caso exista.

Provavelmente essa sua classe `Setup()` possui um método construtor `public function __construct()` onde são iniciadas operações essenciais para o funcionamento dos outros métodos. Por isso (provavelmente) resulta em falhas diversas.

Note que não poderá invocar ou sequer declarar o método construtor como estático:

`Setup::__constructor();`

Consulte a documentação do sistema com o qual está trabalhando.

Comment: Nossa era exatamente isso. Não havia me atentado ao construtor. Dentro dele eu tenho um método que seta algumas configurações iniciais e por isso ocorria o erro de carregamento dos arquivos. Valeu! ;)

Answer (score 5):

Não tem nenhuma outra função, ele é usado para indicar que deve criar um objeto e **chamar o construtor**. Ou seja, chamará o [`__construct()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php).

Em uma classe estática não deveria ter um, mas, se tiver um, ele será executado quando se tenta instanciar e lá pode fazer qualquer maluquice. Se for um *framework* pode estar criando uma série de configurações globais, o que é uma maluquice. *Frameworks* costumam fazer maluquices. Então a variável não precisaria ser usada em lugar algum, ela nem precisa existir. Mesmo que tivesse que fazer essa maluquice, deveria ser através de um método estático e não o construtor.

O problema específico só você poderá avaliar, mas o funcionamento do mecanismo é este.

Avalie se não mudou mais nada que tenha causado o problema.

Comment: Mas esse Framework é pra maluco mesmo em :P

Comment: Eu não estou usando framework. Ainda estou fazendo da forma mais braçal msm! :/

Comment: Então tem u merro enorme no que fez. Mas se você que fez e não sabe porque está acontecendo isso, é mais difícil pra gente que não sabe nada sobre o assunto.

Comment: Foi outra pessoa que fez a classe Setup e eu estava implementando novas classes quando me deparei com aquilo. Mas minha falha foi não me atentar ao construtor da classe msm! De qualquer forma, valeu pela ajuda! :)